# How to properly terminate a QThread from a GUI application?

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I tried using `self.terminate()` in the QThread class, and also `self.thread.terminate()` in the GUI class. I also tried putting `self.wait()` in both cases. However, there are two scenarios that happen:

1) The thread does not terminate at all, and the GUI freezes waiting for the thread to finish. Once the thread finished, the GUI unfreezes and everything is back to normal.

2) The thread indeed does terminate, but at the same time it freezes the entire application.

I also tried using `self.thread.exit()`. No joy.

To further clarify, I am trying to implement a user-abort button in GUI which would terminate the executing of the thread at any point in time.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is the `run()` method:

```
def run(self):
    if self.create:
        print "calling create f"
        self.emit(SIGNAL("disableCreate(bool)"))
        self.create(self.password, self.email)
        self.stop()            
        self.emit(SIGNAL("finished(bool)"), self.completed)

def stop(self):
     #Tried the following, one by one (and all together too, I was desperate):
     self.terminate()
     self.quit()
     self.exit()
     self.stopped = True
     self.terminated = True
     #Neither works
```

And here is the GUI class' method for aborting the thread:

```
def on_abort_clicked(self):
     self.thread = threadmodule.Thread()
     #Tried the following, also one by one and altogether:
     self.thread.exit()
     self.thread.wait()
     self.thread.quit()
     self.thread.terminate()
     #Again, none work
```

Comment: Note: self.terminate === (self.terminated = true), nothing more. For 99% of all implementations.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really help solve the issue.

Comment: There is only one way to safely terminate thread - let it finish all it tasks. To perform it, you have to check thread.terminated before executing hard tasks.

Comment: Well, that certainly is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6):

From the Qt documentation for QThread::terminate:

> **Warning**: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The
>   thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be
>   terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to
>   clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use
>   this function only if absolutely necessary.

It's probably a much better idea to re-think your threading strategy such that you can e.g. use QThread::quit() to signal the thread to quit cleanly, rather than trying to get the thread to terminate this way. Actually calling thread.exit() from within the thread should do that depending on how you have implemented run(). If you'd like to share the code for your thread run method that might hint as to why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hmm. And I assume the `self.create()` method is the time-consuming method in the thread? Generally what you would do in there is something like `while not self.terminated() { do slow operation parts.. }`. Unfortunately I don't know Python well, but looks like there is a threading tutorial [here](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots) that might help

Comment: I tried that as well. It happened to work somewhat (the GUI wouldn't freeze, but the thread would not terminate either). However the oddest thing just happened. I deleted all the `def stop(self)` code in the thread and the `def on_abort_clicked(self)` code in the GUI, and rewrote it. I simply put `self.terminate()` in the thread's `stop()` function and did `self.thread.stop()` in the GUI class. It works like a charm. AFAIK, that's the first thing I tried, and it didn't work before. I probably missed something.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    stop_flag = 1
    ...

#=========500 ms class ===================
class Timer500msThread(QThread):
    signal_500ms = pyqtSignal(str) 
    ....
    def timer500msProcess(self):
        if MainWindow.stop_flag == 0 :
            self.timer_500ms.stop()
#==========
#=========Main Window ===================
        
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
MainWindow.stop_flag=0      #this sets the flag to 0 and when the next 500ms triggers the 
                               #the thread ends
print("Program Ending")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with use of `pyqtSignals` and `pyqtSlots`.
You could create a `pyqtSignal` in your MainWindow-class and use the `aboutToQuit`-function to your `QApplication` instance.
Then you connect this `aboutToQuit`-function with another which emit a signal to the slot in your separate thread.
Then you can define a `stop()` function in this Thread which runs if the signal is emitted.
In this case the thread would not terminate during its work.

**MainWindow:**

```
class mainSignals(QObject):
    isClosed = pyqtSignal()

class mainwindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__()
        self.mainSignal = mainSignals()
        ...
        ...

if __name__ = "__main__":
    # This function runs if the application is closed. 
    # (app.aboutToQuit.connect(windowClose))
    def windowClose():
        window.mainSignal.isClosed.emit() # Emit the signal to the slot in (sepThread)


    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(windowClose)
    window = mainwindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**sepThread**:

```
class sepThread(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(sepThread,self).__init__()
        self._parent = parent
        self.mainOpen = True
        self._parent.mainSignal.isClosed.connect(self.stopThread)
        # If the signal was emitted by the Mainapplication 
        # the stopThread function runs and set the mainOpen-attribute to False

    def stopThread(self):
        self.mainOpen = False
    
        
    def run(self):
        while self.mainOpen == True:
            # Do something in a loop while mainOpen-attribute is True
            ...
            ...
```