# Cancel background task (terminate QThread) in PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, kill, qthread

This question is very much related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928044/how-to-properly-terminate-a-qthread-from-a-gui-application), which doesn't have a solution, but it is not exactly the same.

I would like to ask if there is a way of launching a background task in PyQt, and be able to `kill` it by pressing a button.

My problem is that I have an user interface and some external (3rd party) functions that take a while to compute. In order to not frozen the user interface while the task are computing, I run them on the background using `QThread` and synchronize the UI when they finish using `signals`.

However, I would like to add the option for the external user to press a button and cancel the current task (because the task is not needed/desired anymore).

Something that to me looks as simple as a `kill -9 *task*` in linux, is quite hard/ofuscated to obtain in Qt.

Right now I'm using custom Qthreads of the form of:

```
mythread = Mythread()
mythread.finished.connect(mycallback)
mythread.start()
```

Where `Mythread` inherits [QThread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html) overriding the `run` method.

In the user interface, there is one button that tries to kill that thread by either using:

```
mythread.exit(0)
mythread.quit()
mythread.terminate()
```

None of them works... I'm aware that the documentation states that the `terminate` method does have weird behaviours...

So the question is.. I'm facing this problem wrong? How to kill a QThread? If is not possible, is there any alternative to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you keep a reference to the thread in a member variable of UI class or in a local variable?

Comment: @qurban Yes I do. That's not the problem. The problem is that currently `QThread` doesn't have a killing mechanism.

Comment: Please post the minimal working code, so that I can debug it. I always used to kill the `QThread` using `terminate` method and it always worked. I have gotten no idea why this is not working in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very common mistake to try to kill a `QThread` in the way you're suggesting. This seems to be due to a failure to realise that it's the *long-running task* that needs to be stopped, rather than the thread itself.

The task was moved to the worker thread because it was blocking the main/GUI thread. But that situation doesn't really change once the task is moved. It will block the *worker thread* in exactly the same way that it was blocking the main thread. For the thread to finish, the task itself either has to complete normally, or be programmatically halted in some way. That is, something must be done to allow the thread's `run()` method to exit normally (which often entails breaking out of a blocking loop).

A common way to cancel a long-running task is via a simple stop-flag:

```
class Thread(QThread):
    def stop(self):
        self._flag = False

    def run(self):
        self._flag = True
        for item in get_items():
            process_item(item)
            if not self._flag:
                break
        self._flag = False
```

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that my `run` methods calls 3rd party libraries, say `scikits-learn` trying to learn a classifier, which could take minutes to hours. So my run could look like `self.classifier.train(self.X)`. In this case, which is the best alternative to run it as a thread/subprocess and be able to kill it?

Comment: @imaluengo. If you can't control the long-running task, then you should use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool), rather than threads.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try and come back.